# Does STACK_SIZE of a task affect the task switching delay

Tags: rtos, freertos

If i have two tasks TASK_A and TASK_B.

Stack size of TASK_A = 300

Stack size of TASK_B = 600

**Does context switching time for TASK_A and TASK_B have any dependency on their respective stack size.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, task stack size does not effect context switching time.  Each task has its own stack in an separate range of memory.  During a context switch, the processor's stack pointer register is changed to point to a different task's stack.  The stacks are not copied or moved during a context switch so the stack size does not effect context switching time.

Answer (score 1):

Context switching is the process in which the system switches from one task to another in a multitasking environment. It is a general term. There can be many types of switches like **register**, **thread**, **stack** etc. If you are particularly referring to     **stack frame** switches, then it involves **push** or **pop** operations and some register restore operations, which are constant time operations, atleast in theory. It doesn't depend on the size of the stack itself.